# How tile a texture without repetition in react three fiber

Tags: three.js, textures, react-three-fiber

So I have very simple grass.jpg that I want to use as a texture for plane element. Texture was huge, so I repeated this texture 200 times so it looks much smaller. The problem is that after 200 repetition this plane texture looks so repetitive. I know that are techniques in other 3d softwares that can solve this issue but how to do it with react three fiber ?

[image: repeated grass]

```
const TerrainBox = () => {
  const texture = useTexture('./textures/grass.jpg');
  texture.repeat.set(200, 200);
  texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

  return (
    <mesh receiveShadow>
      <planeBufferGeometry args={[1000, 1000]} attach='geometry' />
      <meshStandardMaterial attach='material' map={texture} side={THREE.DoubleSide} />
    </mesh>
  );
};
```

What can I do so it does not look like copied, pasted side by side images ?

I have been reading documentation but it dosn't seem clear about that to me

Comment: I think you want to use a shader to produce content for a dynamic texture. See these for ideas: 1) https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/70105 
 2) https://codepen.io/ya7gisa0/pen/vGJvWw 
 3) https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/z9ofn0/how_to_solve_repeating_textures/